# I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe a realization that a long held belief is wrong

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, phrase-meaning, descriptive-grammar

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe the realization that what you've always believed is not real. As an example: Let's say you grew up in a country that you where led to believe was far more intellectually and technologically more advanced than it actually is.

Comment: Please be clear, the title suggests you had a [misconception](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misconception) or a [misapprehension](https://www.lexico.com/definition/misapprehension), but the body of the question is asking about the *realization* that your belief was mistaken. That could be an [eye-opener](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eye-opener) or a [revelation](https://www.lexico.com/definition/revelation).

Comment: Word or phrase requests require a sample sentence. Please edit your question to provide one.

Answer (score 4):

**rude awakening** (n.)

> Surprising and unpleasant discovery that one is mistaken
>
> *He thinks he can get by without doing any work, but he is in for a **rude awakening**.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rude%20awakening)

> A sudden and often unwelcome realization.
>
> *They all think Mrs. McCrea has plenty of money, but they're due for a **rude awakening.*** (John O'Hara). [AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=rude%20awakening)

---

> The “pipe dream” of many of our people in the omnipotence of
> legislation is bound to be followed by a **rude awakening**. The
> belief, almost childish in its naïveté, in the all-powerful curative
> effects of law will be rudely shaken. [Richard Bartholdt; "In
> Opposition to the Several  Bills to Restrict Interstate Commerce in
> Certain States"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Argument_of_Hon_Richard_Bartholdt/CSEvAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=his%20belief%20was%20shaken%20rude%20awakening&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover) (1908)

> This might have shaken the faith of the believers in the holy well,
> but fortunately for them no such **rude awakening** appears to have
> marred their confidence in the miraculous powers of the well or of the
> saints. [Rustom Masani; *Folklore of Wells*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Folklore_of_Wells_Being_a_Study_of_Water/EsJTEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=his%20belief%20was%20shaken%20rude%20awakening&pg=PT39&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> Part of Michael's strength emanated from a belief he developed by
> watching a movie about Samson and Delilah. He believed that if he grew
> his hair long, he'd become strong. Indeed, it worked while he was in
> high school. Unfortunately, his belief was in for a **rude awakening**
> when he arrived at USC in the crew-cut era of the fifties. [Tony
> Robbins; *Awaken the Giant Within*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Awaken_The_Giant_Within/iPpyLpX0Y1sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=his%20belief%20%20rude%20awakening&pg=PT209&printsec=frontcover) (2012)

Comment: A few more... [What is another word for rude awakening?](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/rude_awakening.html) In some contexts, a ***revelation*** works better, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I like *revelation* because it can stand in for *change* (in believe(. Many of the other words there may be the emotion one feels about the change, but IMO are not well-suited as a synonym for the realization itself.

Comment: Yes, that distinction can be important. As a cygnet, you might well have been ***labouring under the misapprehension*** that you were just an ugly duckling. Discovering that you were actually growing up into a beautiful swan would hardly be a rude awakening, but it could certainly be a revelation (maybe even an ***epiphany***).

Answer (score 0):

The technical term is [cognitive dissonance](https://www.britannica.com/science/cognitive-dissonance).

> cognitive dissonance, the mental conflict that occurs when beliefs or assumptions are contradicted by new information. The unease or tension that the conflict arouses in people is relieved by one of several defensive maneuvers: they reject, explain away, or avoid the new information; persuade themselves that no conflict really exists; reconcile the differences; or resort to any other defensive means of preserving stability or order in their conceptions of the world and of themselves.

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of realization, though.-)

Answer (score 0):

**To pierce the veil**

> To see through an illusion or find a hidden meaning, to see the truth within a lie.

https://www.phrases.com/phrase/pierce-the-veil_10192